# Bootstrap pull-right pull-left centering on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problem making footer with pull-left and pull-right then center on mobile devices. Currently on desktop it is displaying properly.

Code([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gLmb0yy/2/)):

```
<footer >
<div class="container">
    <p>
      <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
          <strong>Powered by Google</strong>.
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
          <a href="" title="Terms" target="_blank">Terms</a>
          <span class="">|</span>
          <a href="" title="Policy" target="_blank">Policy</a>
      </div>
    </p>
    <BR>
    <p>
        <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
            Please direct all queries to admin@gmail.com
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
            2.1
        </div>
    </p>

</div>
```

As you can see when it is on mobile devices it is displayed as this:
[image]

I want to be able to display it similar to this on mobile device where it is centered:
[image]

Comment: What you're showing as desired output is entirely different content?

Comment: You need to use @media query to control these things: https://jsfiddle.net/1gLmb0yy/5/

Comment: and you have a wrong bootstrap structure, you need to wrap `col-xx-xx` by `row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wrap your `col-***` divs in the `.row` div.
2. I think you don't need `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes. Add `col-sm-push-4` class to make right div move to the page's right border
3. Add custom css to center content on mobile devices, like this:

   `@media (max-width: 767px) {
     .col-sm-4 {
       text-align: center;
     }
   }`

Or add custom class to these divs, if you don't want other `.col-sm-4` divs to have centered content.

https://jsfiddle.net/1gLmb0yy/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use query media to do that, because when the result is pull to right in a small resolution. it will responsive and go to bottom. You can use F12 developer tool to see that.

```
 <footer >
        <div class="container">
              <div class="col-sm-4 row">
                  <strong>Powered by Google</strong>.
                  Please direct all queries to admin@gmail.com
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 row pull-right">
                  <a href="" title="Terms" target="_blank">Terms</a>
                  <span class="">|</span>
                  <a href="" title="Policy" target="_blank">Policy</a>
                  2.1 
              <div/>
             </div>
             </div>
     <footer>
```

Developer tool result.

[image]

Example Media Query

```
  @media (max-width: 767px) {

      .col-sm-6.row.pull-right {
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    }
}
```